# Циклический сдвиг файла

Tags: c

Должен быть обеспечен циклический сдвиг байтов данного файла на заданное число позиций вперед или назад, как если бы файл замыкался в кольцо, где его начало и конец совпадают.  В этом случае каждый байт перемещается на соседнюю позицию в направлении сдвига.  Имя входного файла и количество позиций сдвига указываются в качестве аргументов командной строки после ключей -f и -n соответственно.  Направление сдвига устанавливает знак позиционного аргумента.

Если я правильно понимаю нужно открыть файл и операторами << и >> сдвигать биты. Но как именно реализовать сдвиг байтов в кольцо не совсем понятно.

Comment: Проще всего - откройте новый файл, перепишите сначала кусок с k-го байта до конца (k  величина сдвига), потом с начала до k-го байта. Потом удалите исходный файл, а новый переименуйте...

Comment: Как решить эту задачу для массива байт вы понимаете?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я так понимаю можно работать с массивом символов, т.к. 1 символ = 1 байт?

Comment: Да. Читаете файл в массив. Обрабатываете. Записываете обратно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy благодарю